# Not seeing logs for program managed by systemd

Tags: ubuntu, python, systemd, journald

I'm using systemd to manage a program on Ubuntu 16.  I can't seem to get the logs from the program to output to `journalctl` or `/var/log/syslog`.  The journald configuration is the default, which should forward all log messages < debug to syslog, at least. Here is the journald conf:

```
>> cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See journald.conf(5) for details.

[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitInterval=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
```

The program definition is:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Program
After=network.target

[Service]
User=vagrant
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant/transporter
Environment=PORT=8080
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 catcher.py
```

When I do a `print` call in the program I don't see any output in `journalctl` or `/var/log/syslog`.  It appears that the logs are not hitting `journalctl`, which is the first problem, but I don't understand how to change the configuration for it to get those.  If I run the program manually (`python3.5 catcher.py`) from a shell I do see the print output on the console.

I have tried running changing ExecStart to use `python3.5 -u` so as to not buffer stdout, but that did not work. I've also tried changing the journald.conf `ForwardToConsole` setting to yes, and restarted the `systemd-journald` service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by using the [python-systemd](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd/) wrapper package as described in  [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588421/how-to-log-to-journald-systemd-via-python).  Here is the gist of it:

```
import logging
from systemd.journal import JournalHandler

log = logging.getLogger('demo')
log.addHandler(JournalHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.info("sent to journal")
```

Note, you'll need to install the OS system package of `python-systemd` (e.g. `apt-get install python-systemd` on Ubuntu), not the pip package.  Apparently they are different.